# error and warning messages in R console and blank downloaded plot in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

i am fairly new to shiny. i am trying to build ui that has drop downs (and plots/data display) that are conditional on an initial selection field. i have made a simplified example using the `USArrests` data set...

https://gist.github.com/guyabel/4059ae889dea4b8ca0ca

or

`shiny::runGist('4059ae889dea4b8ca0ca')`

i have a couple of things that i can not figure out.

1. i get error messages in the R console relating to the default plot (and subsequent plots).

   `Warning in min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf`
2. i get error messages in the R console relating to the data...

   `Warning in matrix(align.tmp[(2 - pos):(ncol(x) + 1)], nrow = nrow(x), ncol = ncol(x) +  : data length exceeds size of matrix`
3. the download plot button returns a blank plot
4. when i select all from the first drop down i get no plot. (i guess this is related to 1)?)

any ideas how to solve any of these (i think they might all be related)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 +2) Check the Shiny processing model: http://rstudio.github.io/shiny/tutorial/#execution-scheduling

Simplest solution for your case is to check if df2 is already filled with data:

```
  getplot <- reactive({
    if(!is.null(input$crime)) {
        df2<-getdf()$df2
        if(dim(df2)[1] != 0){
            ...
        }
```

and there will be no more errors / warnings.

3) as far as I know you are not allowed to call a reactive function in there! Copy all your code from getplot into content= ... and it should be working.

And add a "contentType = 'image/png'" to take care that a png file will be created.

4) you are trying to plot numerical and factorial data? I expect something like this

```
plot(df2[,1:4])
```

will be the solution.

In general: You should get familiar to data frames. Your data perfectly fits into a data frame and not a list. This will fix several conversion problems